# NOT NULL constraint failed: core_profile.user_id

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a model named Profile which is created to extend the User auth model. I have created two forms one is UserForm and ProfileForm. In register.html template I show this two forms and wish to save in the database through the user.

But it constantly shows the exception: Integrity Error

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: core_profile.user_id
```

whenever I try to submit the post filling out all the fields and hit submit button.

Here are my models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

And here is my view for posting the forms:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import SignUpForm, ProfileForm


@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.profile.birth_date = user_form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.save()
            raw_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        user_form = SignUpForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

And here are the forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Profile


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'birth_date')


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio', 'location')
```

### Thank you,

Comment: Post the complete error track trace!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying to save the profile_form, it doesn't know to which user it is related to. And in your case, when you save the user form, it will create the profile, and what you need to do is just update the profile of you saved user, so I suggest something like:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.profile.bio = profile_form.cleaned_data.get('bio')
            user.profile.location = profile_form.cleaned_data.get('location')
            user.profile.save()  

     ...
```

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, can you then mark answer as a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Gagik Sukiasyan's answer: I added some additional things to reduce errors / ease your life:

- `transaction.atomic` -> if errors occur, the database is being rolled back
- `and profile_form.is_valid()` makes sure profile_form is validated
- instead of going through the profile attributes manually I added a loop

Modified Code:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def register(request):
    """ register a new user view """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            for field in profile_form.changed_data:
                setattr(user.profile, field, profile_form.cleaned_data.get(field))
            user.profile.save()
```